# Python Predicates and Conditionals

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, predicate, numba

A user on github reported a bug on the following code using numba no python mode:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def foo():
    a = np.ones(1, np.bool_)
    if a > 0:
        print('truebr')
    else:
        print('falsebr')

foo()
```

He was told that the expression `a > 0` is not a predicate but rather a conditional.
In order to fix it he was to "Wrap conditionals in truth to create predicates".

Does this mean that `(a > 0) == True` would fix the bug that comes up in numba or something else.

https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/3901/commits/598cdd1707fdeb11b8f1d70aef2d3e36ef37bd34. Is this the fix for these types of errors in numba?

Comment: No, it means that if `a == array([1])`, then `a > 0` is the array `array([True])`, which doesn't have a truth value of its own at all. You have to be explicit: if `a > 0` is supposed to mean *all* comparisons returned `True`, use `if (a>0).all()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python (not `numba`) the function works:

```
In [412]: def foo(): 
     ...:     a = np.ones(1, np.bool_) 
     ...:     if a > 0: 
     ...:         print('truebr') 
     ...:     else: 
     ...:         print('falsebr') 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [413]: foo()                                                                                
truebr
```

But if `a` is an array with more values:

```
In [414]: def foo(): 
     ...:     a = np.ones(2, np.bool_) 
     ...:     if a > 0: 
     ...:         print('truebr') 
     ...:     else: 
     ...:         print('falsebr') 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [415]: foo()                                                                                
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

If I try your function in `njit` I get a long traceback; too long to show or analyze, but it essentially tells me it can't be done in `njit` mode.  Given the above value error, I'm not surprised.  `njit` isn't allowing for 'just-one' Truth value array.

As a general rule, when using `numba` you should iterate.  That's its main purpose - to run `numpy/python` problems that would otherwise be too expensive to iterate.  Don't count on `numba` to handle all the nuances of Python.

If I change the function to test each element of `a`, it works:

```
In [421]: @numba.njit 
     ...: def foo(): 
     ...:     a = np.array([True]) 
     ...:     for i in a: 
     ...:         if i > 0: 
     ...:             print('truebr') 
     ...:         else: 
     ...:             print('falsebr') 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [422]: foo()                                                                                
truebr
```

An `all` (or `any`) wrapper also works:

```
In [423]: @numba.njit 
     ...: def foo(): 
     ...:     a = np.array([True]) 
     ...:     if (a > 0).all(): 
     ...:         print('truebr') 
     ...:     else: 
     ...:         print('falsebr') 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [424]: foo()                                                                                
truebr
```